# Laravel Eloquent pagination control page number with route

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination, eloquent

`Articles::paginate(10)`
This code will return the 1st 10 articles, what if I want to return the next 10 articles with route? For example the url `mypage.com/articles/2` will return the 2nd 10 articles from database.
This is so far what I have:
 
**Route:**

```
Route::get('articles/{page_number}', 'Controller@getArticles')
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getArticles($page_num)
{
    $perPage = 10;
    Articles::getPaginator()->setCurrentPage($page_num);
    $articles = Articles::paginate($perPage);
    return $articles;
}
```

Can I have something like `Articles::pageNumber($page_number)->paginate($perPage);`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Laravel paginator automatically checks for the the value of `page` in query string and uses it to paginate the results. The result also automatically generates the next and previous links to help you add them directly. You don't need to change anything to make it work.

In your case you can use `$articles->links()` in your view to generate the pagination navigation buttons. But if you want to manually set the page then you can do this.

```
$articles = Articles::paginate(5, ['*'], 'page', $pageNumber);
```

The default paginate method takes the following parameters.

```
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null);
```

The default convention is

```
mypage.com/articles?page=2
mypage.com/articles?page=3
```

Also if you use `$articles->links()` to generate the navigation button, you can also customize the css.

Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination for more info

Comment: I got error `Method setCurrentPage does not exist.`

Comment: @Newbie my bad, it's been a long time since i worked with pagination. I've updated my answer and tested the code to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$results= DB::table('subscribers')->select('id', 'name', 'email')->paginate(20);

$results->count();

$results->currentPage();

$results->firstItem();

$results->hasMorePages();

$results->lastItem();

$results->lastPage(); (Not available when using simplePaginate)

$results->nextPageUrl();

$results->perPage();

$results->previousPageUrl();

$results->total(); (Not available when using simplePaginate)

$results->url($page);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).