# Laravel pagination add page number

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

Am sending a get request and adding the pagination value but now i would like to attach the page

So in my URL I have

```
http://localhost:8080/users?paginator=10&page=1
```

The value of page and paginator are controlled from frontend(angular4)

So in my controller I have

```
class UserController extends Controller{

 public function index(){
   return User::paginate($request->paginator);
 }
}
```

The above works for the paginator value but now how do I attach the page number?

Answer (score 2):

```
return User::paginate($request->paginator, ['*'], 'page', $request->page);
```

The default paginate method takes the following parameters.

```
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null);
```

For further details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077438/laravel-eloquent-pagination-control-page-number-with-route) link.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results):

> By default, the current page is detected by the value of the page query string argument on the HTTP request.